# \b regex for end of word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm able to use /b to replace the first character of a word, however can't figure out how to do the same for the last character of a word. Anyone have insight?

eg. 
result = lowStr.replace(/\b\w/g, x=>x.toLowerCase());
to make the fist letter lowercase, now how would I apply this to the last letter?

TIA!

Comment: With `/\w\b/g`...

Comment: oh. hahahahhaha, that's so simple. great, thank you!!